# CoreData generated 'class definition' is not found

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

I've a hierarchy of 4 abstract entities in CoreData that ends with a non-abstract entity:

`[Element]-[AttributedElement]-[Object]-[Stroke]-[StrokeLine]`

If I instantiate the non-abstract entity (`StrokeLine`) and try to access a property of the root entity (`Element`) I get an error `Value of type 'StrokeLine' has no member 'lineNumber'`.

```
let object=StrokeLine(context: managedObjectContext)
object.lineNumber=1
```

I checked the `DerivedData` folder and all class files are there.

If I use 'Jump to Definition' it can only jump to the file for `StrokeLine`. For it's super class a '?' is displayed.

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1

How can I make sure that the other class files are also compiled/read?

Comment: Off topic but why do you have 4 (!) abstract classes in a hierarchy, maybe you should re-think your design.

Comment: Different subclasses inherit at different points in the hierarchy. I believe abstract classes are rather cheap in CoreData?

Comment: For me it is not about Core Data but about having a design with so many levels in a hierarchy and so many being abstract. Maybe you should look at composition instead of inheritance as a design solution for instance. Anyway this is off-topic in regard to your question